# Append jQuery datatable as <span> instead of <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable next to my globe like [this one](http://maulik-kamdar.com/code/meteorViz/). I was able to create the table using [jQuery datatable](https://datatables.net/). However, it's creating the table in a div instead of in a span next to my globe. Screenshot below: 
[image]
I want to achieve an effect somewhat like this:
[image]
I believe I have to use the span tag. #currentInfo is the div that the globe is in).
I tried

```
$("#currentInfo").append("<span id='createSpan'></span>");
$("#createSpan").append("<table id='example' class='display compact' width='50%'></table>");
```

Nothing seems to change. The table is created as a div above the globe. So I tried:

```
$("#currentInfo").append("<span><table id='example' class='display compact' width='50%'></table></span>");
```

The result is still the same. The data returned is `<div><span>data</span><span>data</span>.....</div>`

The below code skips including the table completely.

```
$("#currentInfo").append("<span id='example' class='display compact' width='50%'></span>");
```

and I am also getting an error: *DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (SPAN).* For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2. This leads me to believe that jQuery datatable has to be appended in the format below with the **table** tag, and a div will be created and wrap around the data automatically.

```
 $("#elementId").append("<table id='example' class='display compact' width='50%'></table>");
```

I am able to add span text by doing

```
$("#currentInfo").append("<span id='temp'>Add span text here</span>");
```

to the globe.
I could style my data and just append it as a span, but there are so many read to use perks that come with the jQuery datatable (sort, format, etc.)

Is there a way that I can override the jQuery datatable div property, so it creates wrap the table in a span tag instead of a div? Or can anymore suggest a different data library that allows me to achieve this?

Comment: And why don't you style the wrapper DIV to behaves like a SPAN??? You could set it position to absolute with some specific z-index and warpped this DIV and your globe element to a common container. There is many ways to do what you are expecting but you should provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue to get, i guess, the best solution which would fit your needs

Comment: Understood the issue might be hard to replicate without a minimalistic sample. Trying the z-index with absolute position now.

Comment: Yes, styling the dataTable wrapper to an `absolute` position would be the right way to solve this problem.  I am pretty sure the sphere has some absolute styling as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) and [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) for the enlightenment. I was thinking the long and winding way to do something simple. The globe does have absolute styling. The use of absolute and and z-index solved my problem beautifully. Posting my solution for anyone who wishes to add table to their globe as a future reference:

```
#example_wrapper {
    padding: 5%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 700px;
    z-index: 3
} 

#globeImageContainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  }

canvas {
    right: 0px;
    left: 5%;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Note that #globeImageContainer is my custom div where I put my globe and the table in. #example_wrapper came with the jQuery datatable library. Canvas come with the globe library.